# Can a non-EEA student with Dutch residence permit do a fulltime internship in Prague?

Tags: eu, resident-permit, education, czech-republic

Do I have permission to work in Prague (Czech Republic) under an internship provided the following conditions:

- I'm a non-EEA national (Vietnamese)
- with a valid Dutch residence permit, for 'study' purposes
- fulltime internship in Prague for 6 weeks
- internship is a prerequisite of my Master study program.

What do I need to do to obtain a permit to work for an international company in the Czech Republic?
What does my employer need to do?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't do it based on your Dutch residence permit. Unless I am wrong about that, it would then depend on the Czech rules (which I don't know) but I suspect you might need a visa/permit. Maybe if you are not receiving any monetary compensation it does not matter? Hopefully someone will be able to provide a definitive answer…

Answer (score 1):

You can find the information (in English) about foreign employment in Czech Republic on the portal of [Czech Ministry of Labour and Social Affairs](https://portal.mpsv.cz/sz/zahr_zam). Note that the law was changed a few months ago, and some English pages state that English translation is still in the process of proofreading.

Answer (score 1):

Type D residency permits are essentially equivalent to short-term Schengen visas when it comes to other countries. The Czech consulate to say in New York has the [following to say](http://www.mzv.cz/consulate.newyork/en/visa_and_consular_information/visa/short_term_visa_stay_up_to_90_days/visa_for_a_stay_up_to_90_days_for_the.html) about working on a short-term visa:

> **employment** (work permit issued by the Employment Office or employment contract, if the type of work is exempt from the work permit in accordance with Act. No. 435/2004 Coll. on employment)

The list of exemptions from needing a work permit is available at paragraph 98 of law No. 435/2004, none which unfortunately applies to your particular situation, regardless of whether the internship is paid or not.

Therefore the answer is: **no**, you cannot legally work in Czech Republic without applying for additional visas.